# Problems on Divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling in the following problem: 
$ S \subset R^3$ is a region in divergence theorem. 
$\vec{n}$ is outward normal to the surface of $S$. 
Then, what does $div \vec{F}=0$ mean in the divergence theorem?  Where $F:R^3\to R^3 $ is a $C'$ function.(and conversly)

My intuition says that Since $div \vec{F}=0$ then $\iint_{\partial { S}} \langle \vec{F},\vec{n}\rangle ds=0$. But I would like to know its geometric meaning as well as computations:

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No sources or sinks for $F$. Perhaps only swirling around inside the region.

Comment: I am not sure you are intending to mean. Only information we have about $F$ is $C'$ and $div F=0$.